# Android Services

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, потоки-данных, service

1. Есть класс, который имплементит *Runnable*. В нем есть несколько методов.
2. И есть другой класс, в котором создается Thread, при нажатии кнопки.
3. Есть еще кнопка, в которая должна останавливать мой поток. Но при нажатии, она только делает вид что останавливает, поток в логе все равно продолжает жить.

Примерно догадываюсь, что поток можно перенести в *AndroidService*, и он тогда будет отдельным процессом, которым я смогу управлять. Но не знаю как.

Вот так вызываю свой поток

```
testRunningThread = new Thread(util);
testRunningThread.start();
```

`util` - это просто объект моего Runnable класса.

Comment: а как Вы останавливаете поток? По правилам - нужно добавить потоку специальную переменную, которую поток будет проверять время от времени (эту проверку Вы сами пишете) и завершать свою роботу, если она сменила состояние.

Второй способ - использовать [interrupt](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()).

Answer (score 1):

В классе, расширяющем Runnable создать паблик булеан поле, которое будет означать, нужно ли завершать поток, и в методе run() периодически(если он большой), или один раз(если не очень) проверять, нужно ли завершать поток.

Answer (score 0):

`Service` к треду отношения не имеет. Остановка потока означает просто завершение (выход из ) метода `Thread.run()`

Возможно вы путаете жизнь объекта `Thread` с жизнью потока. То что поток завершился еще не означает что объект умер. Объект умрет когда на него не будет ссылок и когда сборщик мусора посчитает что надо его уничтожить.

Comment: Простите, не так сформулировал вопрос. На свой поток я могу поставить тольк ограничение по времени. И тогда, когда его timeOut вышел, он все равно не прекращает жить в фоне. 

И я себе думаю так, что бы загнать свой поток, в сервис. Я вызываю сам сервис 
onStartCommand()
и его принудительно убиваю
onDestroy()

Сейчас нет доступа к проекту, просто на уровне теории думаю как правильно сделать.

Comment: Какой-то сложный замут для убийства потока (Создать сервис и грохнуть его,что бы тем самым остановить поток). Такое даже в страшном сне не приснится...

Кстати,чтобы Service выполнялся в другом процессе нужно указать это явно в манифесте. Если этого не сделать, то сервис будет работать в процессе, в котором работает ваше приложение с UI элементами.